# Is there any advantage of using asset helper function to instead of absolute URL

Tags: laravel, url, assets

Is understand there is an advantage of using asset helper instead of relative URL like when visiting `/blog/posts` relative won't fetch the styles but using asset helper will. But I currently see no difference of using absolute and asset helper. Do we have situations where asset will work and absolute won't?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" />
```

Comment: What if your application gets moved to be loaded from a subdirectory?

Comment: dynamic vs not dynamic... the advantage is that if the application changes, it will not break